# How to select a sub-fields of a document using N1ql query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Can I Select the child element of a particular field using N1ql Query???

Example:

```
{
  "content": {
    "_id": "88w73c9e-f7ed-4816-7778-5247e69cd77450",
    "_type": "Publish",
    "author": "abcd",
    "book": {
      "$ref": "03ee49ec-4452-4ebs-9f49-9f3aa4rra53f",
      "_type": "Book"
    }
  }
}
```

- How to fetch `$ref` and `_type` from book field??
- How can I write a select query for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to select fields from a sub object uses the dot notation.

For example to get the fields from all the documents in the `test` bucket :

```
SELECT content.book.`$ref`, content.book._type FROM test;
```

- `` SELECT content.book.`$ref`, content.book._type ``: These are the fields that are selected from all the documents in the `test` bucket.

  - The `` `$ref` `` is in back ticks because dollar is a reserved character.
- `FROM test`: This is the bucket query will execute against.

The query would return the following information:

```
[
  {
    "$ref": "03ee49ec-4452-4ebs-9f49-9f3aa4rra53f",
    "_type": "Book"
  }
]
```

---

To do a query base on the content of the document then the following query could be used:

```
SELECT content.book.`$ref`, content.book._type FROM test WHERE content. author = "abcd";
```

For more information about N1QL see the Couchbase [documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/getting-started/try-a-query.html) and [N1QL tutorial](https://query-tutorial.couchbase.com/tutorial/#1)